# "Chose" or another word?

Tags: verbs

I recently learnt the the past form of "choose" is a rarely used word in English. (So is "chosen" used in present perfect.) So instead of saying:

> "I finally chose the dress for the party"
>
> "I didn't choose appetizer from the menu because my wife chose it for me."
>
> "I haven't chosen the dish yet"
>
> "You didn't choose the right job for you"
>
> "I haven't chosen the place for my vacation yet"

More natural would be:

> "haven't decided on the appetizer"
>
> "decide where to go on vacation"

Or are there some other options? What would be most natural way to say those sentences? Do you use the verb "chose" often?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Pick* is often used instead of chose, so you'd more usually say 'you didn't *pick* the right job'. The party dress sentence is interesting - saying "I finally chose..." suggests that there was a choice of a particular number of dresses, maybe ones you own already, so you've decided between them. If, though, you went to a store and bought a dress, after looking several times at various dresses, you'd say "I finally *found* rather than chose.

Otherwise *decide* is often used, exactly as you've given examples already.

As for the appetizer, "I didn't choose..." could be replaced with "I didn't *decide on*" or "I didn't *pick*", but "my wife chose it for me" would usually remain the same, though "my wife *picked* it for me" might also be used.

The sentences you quote are structured merely to demonstrate the difference between chose and choose; they're all accurate, but in reality, there are other ways to say the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Who told you that? *Chose* is the past tense of *choose*, and *chosen* is the past participle. Both are perfectly normal.

Comment: The macmillan dictionary didn't mark this word as red, and "red words" according to that dictionary are the words that occur in 90% of texts and conversations: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/chose

Comment: I think that with *choose*, just because of its meaning, people are more likely to use the past perfect than the past tense. But it's ***not*** a big difference ... It might be that *chose* occurs in 89% of texts, and *chosen* occurs in 91% of texts. This would mean that *chosen* gets one red star, and *chose* gets none, but it wouldn't mean that people avoid using *chose*. As Barrie says, people use it.

Comment: However, I'm afraid you misunderstood the concept of Macmillan's word marking. If the word is black it means that it occurs in less than 10% of the texts.

Comment: I'll bet that 'seventy-nine' occurs in less than 10% of the texts. But it is sometimes just the right word.

Comment: @Edwin: I bet [*twenty-two*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-22_(logic)#Significance_of_the_number_22) and [*forty-two*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_(number)) are the right words more often than *seventy-nine*.

Comment: @FF: I was trying not to be too obvious.

Comment: From Macmillan: *"90% of the time, speakers of English use just 7,500 words in speech and writing. These words appear in red, and are graded with stars. One-star words are frequent, two-star words are more frequent, and three-star words are the most frequent."* I think what this means is that if you know 7,500 words, you will know 90% of the words in a sample of text. ([This webpage says 6000 words is enough,](http://www.fltr.ucl.ac.be/fltr/germ/etan/bibs/vocab/cup.html) but I'm sure it depends on which texts you look at, and whether you count *choose, chose, chosen* as one word or three.)

Comment: Numbers like seventy-five is a different thing. "Chose" is a verb. "27" cannot be replaced by another word nor can be "apple" or "horse" and that is obvious. I'm not saying that "chose" is a weird word. I was wondering if other verbs are used frequently to replace its past meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Your premise is wrong. The Macmillan dictionary you are looking at does not put stars on [past](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/was) and [past perfect](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/been) verb forms unless they consider that the past perfect tense also has an independent definition as an adjective (or other part of speech). Thus, *chosen* has a star because it's used an adjective, but *chose* does not.

Comment: I didn't know that. That explains a lot. Thank you very much for pointing that out.